# Javascript condition to check array length

Tags: javascript

I have an array returned from server response, which has 3 possibilities, i need to check on UI;

> 1. if length is 0..do something
> 2. if length is 1...do something
> 3. length > 1 ...do something

Is there a better way to write the below JS code, given the above conditions ?

```
if (myArray.length == 0) {

} else if (myArray.length == 1) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Different? Several. Better? No, they're all the same, really.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can always use `switch`:

```
switch (myArray.length) {
  case 0:
    doSomething(); break;
  case 1:
    doSomethingElse(); break;
  default:
    doSomethingCompletelyDifferent();
}
```

The benefit is that switch expression will be calculated just once, unlike with `if-elseif-else`.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is fine. Alternately, you could use `switch`:

```
switch (myArray.length) {
    case 0:
        // Empty
        break;
    case 1:
        // Has one entry
        break;
    default:
        // Has more than one entry
        break;
}
```

Or you sometimes see dispatch tables, but it's really mostly relevant when you're calling functions to start with:

```
var dispatch = {
    0: handleArrayEmpty,
    1: handleArrayOneEntry,
    multi: handleArrayMultipleEntries
};

(dispatch[myArray.length] || dispatch.multi)();
```

That's a bit out there, of course. :-) It makes use of [JavaScript's curiously-powerful OR operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to handle the case where `myArray.length` didn't match any of the entries in `dispatch`.

Comment: Like the dispatch object approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (myArray.length) {
                  case 0:
                   // do somthing
                  break;

                  case 1:
                   // do somthing   
                  break;

                  default:
                   // do somthing   
                  break ;
        }
```